# javascript - date should be from 1st Nov of current year to 10th Feb of next year

Tags: javascript, date, date-range

i'm putting some condition that date should be from 1st Nov of current year to 10th Feb of next year

This is what i have tried

```
if((date.getDate() >= 1 && date.getMonth() === 11 && date.getFullYear()) && (date.getDate() <= 10 && date.getMonth() === 2 && date.getFullYear + 1)){
   condition satisfied
}
```

Obviously which is not working. What is the proper way in javascript to put this condition.

Comment: `getMonth()` is 0 based so nov is 10 and feb is 1.  `&& date.getFullYear()` has no checking condition so is always truthy.

Comment: You may considering using **EPOCH** as `EPOCH = new Date().getTime()` to compare with `var d1 = Date.UTC(2018, 10, 1);` instead of checking multiple conditions

Comment: @AlexK.—it's not truthy if the year is 0000. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works:

```
function check(date) {
  currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
  return  date > new Date(currentYear + '-11-01') && date < new Date(currentYear + 1 + '-02-10')
}

console.log(check(new Date())); // currently false
console.log(check(new Date('2018-12-01'))); // true
console.log(check(new Date('2019-01-31'))); // true
```

Use it as follows:

```
if(check(date)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that `new Date('2018-12-01')` will be treated as UTC, but *getFullYear* returns the local year, so this will error at apparently infrequent and random times unless the host timezone offset is +00:00. A good answer should include an explanation of the OP's issue and how your code fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work because when comparing dates, you have to compare the entire date, not just the parts. You can can get the current year from a Date instance, then use it to create the limit dates to compare it to, e.g.

```js
function testDate(date) {
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();
  return date >= new Date(year, 10, 1) &&       // 1 Nov current year
         date <= new Date(year + 1, 1, 11) - 1; // 10 Feb next year at 23:59:59.999
}

// Some tests
[new Date(2018,9,31),  // 31 Oct 2018
 new Date(2018,10,1),  //  1 Nov 2018
 new Date(2019,1,10),  // 10 Feb 2018
 new Date(2019,1,11),  // 11 Feb 2018
 new Date()]           // Current date
 .forEach(function(date) {
   console.log(date.toLocaleString(undefined, {day: '2-digit',
     month:'short', year:'numeric'}) + ': ' + testDate(date));
 });
```

All of the above dates are treated as local for the host.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
let checkDifferenceDate = moment() >= moment("12/01/"+moment().year()) && moment() <= moment("01/31/"+moment().add(1,'year').year())
if(checkDifferenceDate){
    //You logic here !
}
```